# Vue component watcher not handling error in promise

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a Vue component with a watcher:

```js
watch: {
  objectId() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reject(new Error("err"))
    })
  }
}
```

And then I have an error handler like this:

```js
Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err) { alert('oh no!') }
```

My error handler triggers when errors happen outside the watcher, but not the error triggered by the promise in the watcher. I do see the error in the console. The watcher is watching a prop that is coming from Vue router, if that matters.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$ vue --version
@vue/cli 4.2.3
```

Comment: A rejected promise isn't itself an error and since watchers don't make use of any returned values, there's no unhandled promise rejection either. Why are you using a `Promise` in your watcher anyway?

Comment: it's an asynchronous `fetch`. when i run the same thing in `mounted`, the unhandled rejection triggers the errorHandler, which then tells the user something is wrong. i'm trying to get the same behavior for the watcher.

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10009

Comment: argh. okay. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that PR's been sitting around for a while now. I guess you'll just need to handle the errors manually for now.